# Place specific person on separate layer with GetOrgChart

Tags: getorgchart

Is it possipble to put an (e.g.) assistent on a separate level in an organization chart powered by GetOrgChart?

[image: desired organization chart]

Comment: Maybe someone of the GetOrgChart team can help since this is the official support channel?

Comment: The current version does not support assistance functionality